# How to specify prerequisite external program for Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a project that requires an external program to function; is there an easy way to declare this dependency? Right now the tests just fail when the program isn't there, and all I get in the terminal is a scrolling list of test failures caused by IOException; I have to dig into the log to see that it's due to a missing executable. I'd like to be able to detect the absence early and abort with a helpful message instead.